# Use arrays and for loops but no strings or any classes

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

```
void printEncodingCodonSequences (
            char aminoAcid1,
            char aminoAcid2,
            char aminoAcid3, 
            char aminoAcid4,
            char aminoAcid5
);
```

Given a protein fragment consisting of 5 amino acid symbols as input, print out (on the screen) all the 
diﬀerent codon sequences (one sequence per line) that translate to this protein fragment. The input can be in 
any case, and if any of the input is invalid, the function should print ‘?’ in a single line.

Here is an example: the 
protein fragment MWQWH can be translated by these four codon sequences, and therefore the for input: ‘M’, ’W’, ’Q’, ’W’, ’H‘ (or ‘m’, ‘W’, ‘q’, ‘W’, ‘H’), the function should print the following:

```
ATGTGGCAATGGCAT
ATGTGGCAGTGGCAT
ATGTGGCAATGGCAC
ATGTGGCAGTGGCAC
```

I don't expect you to answer it all, just a hint how to do it. For this task, no string or any container classes are allowed! I was told I have to use nested loops with arrays.

[image]

in this project protein fragments are composed of 5 amino acid(input as their symbols), if  aminoacid has more than 1 codon it will print in new line.

Comment: Regarding the question: It's hard to give a hint for the answer since most of StackOverflow users don't know how protein fragments work. Can you add some piece of information about that?

Comment: Have you written any code? Maybe it would be easier to start if you pretend each amino acid is encoded by one unique triplet (so there will be just one encoding in the output). Once you nail it down you can start thinking about amino acids encoded by multiple triplets.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that you should use loops to implement this: This can be programmed using *five nested loops*. In each loop, you go through *all of the possible translating codon triplets* for one amino acid symbol. That's the basic idea.

The following pseudo-code could serve as a start:

```
for each translating codon triplet codon1 for aminoAcid1:
    for each translating codon triplet codon2 for aminoAcid2:
        for each translating codon triplet codon3 for aminoAcid3:
            for each translating codon triplet codon4 for aminoAcid4:
                for each translating codon triplet codon5 for aminoAcid5:
                    print codon1 + codon2 + codon3 + codon4 + codon5
                end for
            end for
        end for
    end for
end for
```

What you have now to do is to write these loops in C++ using raw arrays. You know in advance for each amino acid symbol which (and how many) codon triplets are candidates we have to walk through in the loop. Store them as constant arrays and access this array in the loop using the provided amino acid from the function parameters.

Since you should not use strings and containers, you are forced to use C-strings (char arrays) and raw arrays of such to encode the table from above in C++. The variables in the pseudo-code (`codon1` ... `codon5`) should then be just `const char*` (C-strings) and can be printed using either `cout` or `printf`.

The table from above can be written as an array like the following. Note that I wrote every row of your table as one C-string which starts with the letter encoding the amino acid symbol, then followed by a "list" of triplets. All of these triplets are 0-terminated (which makes it possible to point to them as C-strings). To iterate through the triplets you have to just find the null terminating character and increment this pointer by one. If this pointer is non-null, there is another triplet coming. If it is null (note that at the end of these lines, another null will be added as it is added to every string literal), this was the last triplet.

```
const char *codons[] = {
    "AGCT\0GCC\0GCA\0GCG\0",
    "RCGT\0CGC\0CGA\0CGG\0AGA\0AGG\0",
    // ...
    "*TAA\0TGA\0TAG\0"
};
```

Using a utility function which finds the correct row from this table, the loops can then be written as (here for the first acid symbol):

```
for(const char *codon1 = codonRow(aminoAcid1); codon1 += strlen(codon1); codon1 != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

In this loop, the initialization uses the utility function (see below) which returns the row from the table but excluding the first character (so it points to the first codon triplet for the given acid). The increment operation just increases this pointer by the C-string length (which will result in `codon1` pointing just after the next null terminating character). If this is null, we are done.

The nice thing is that in each iteration of this loop, `codon1` points to a C-string (well, it points just in the middle of a string literal of the array from above) and will be terminated appropriately. So printing `codon1` will just print 3 characters.

And this is the utility function which was used in the loop above, which searches for a particular character within the table and returns this row:

```
const char *codonRow(char aminoAcid)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(codons)/sizeof(*codons); ++i) {
        const char *row = codons[i];   // Fetch the row from the array
        if (row[0] == aminoAcid)       // Compare the amino acid symbol
            return row + 1;            // Remove the amino acid symbol
    }
    // error:
    std::cerr << "No such amino acid: " << aminoAcid << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to ignore that you were told exactly how many codons there are, and describe a more general solution.

You know that each codon translates to exactly 3 characters, so you can calculate the size of the required buffer up front.  In your case you can use a fixed-size buffer of course.  Remember to leave space for the terminating NUL character.  This output buffer will be an array.  That looks like this:

```
void printEncodingCodonSequences(
        char aminoAcid1,
        char aminoAcid2,
        char aminoAcid3, 
        char aminoAcid4,
        char aminoAcid5         )
{
     char outputBuffer[16]; // 5 codons, exactly
     char codons[] = { aminoAcid1, aminoAcid2, aminoAcid3, aminoAcid4, aminoAcid5 };
     findCodonEncodingCombinations(outputBuffer, outputBuffer, codons, 5);
}
```

Next, you need to map each codon to all possible sequences, and repeat this for however many codons you are given.  Because this is a combinatorial problem, it lends itself very well to recursion.  The function takes the first codon, and iterates through the different possible encodings.  In each iteration, it calls itself again to handle the remaining codons.

```
int findCodonEncodingCombinations( char* outputBuffer, char* outputPos, char* codons, int remaining )
{
    if (remaining == 0) {
        *outputPos = 0;
        puts(outputBuffer);
        puts("\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int combinations = 0;

    switch (*codon) {
        case 'D': // GAT, GAC
        case 'd':
            outputPos[0] = 'G';
            outputPos[1] = 'A';
            outputPos[2] = 'T';
            combinations += findCodonEncodingCombinations(outputBuffer, outputPos + 3, codons + 1, remaining - 1);
            outputPos[2] = 'C';
            combinations += findCodonEncodingCombinations(outputBuffer, outputPos + 3, codons + 1, remaining - 1);
            break;
    }

    return combinations;
}
```

Actually, loops aren't particularly helpful with this problem.  You can however use one for verifying that all inputs are valid, like:

```
void printEncodingCodonSequences(
        char aminoAcid1,
        char aminoAcid2,
        char aminoAcid3, 
        char aminoAcid4,
        char aminoAcid5         )
{
     char outputBuffer[16]; // 5 codons, exactly
     char codons[] = { aminoAcid1, aminoAcid2, aminoAcid3, aminoAcid4, aminoAcid5 };
     if (!validateCodons(codons, 5)) return;
     findCodonEncodingCombinations(outputBuffer, outputBuffer, codons, 5);
}

bool validateCodons( char* codons, int count )
{
    while (count--) {  // it's a loop :)
        switch (*codons++) {
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
            //...
                break;

            default: // unrecognized codon
                puts("?\n");
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Obviously, you need to fill in the many other codon mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to translate amino acid sequences to codon sequences.  So the first thing you'll need is a table to translate amino acid codes to codons.  Since you're not allowed to use classes, a table means an array.  Since each amino acid may translate to more than one codon, you need an array of arrays:

```
#define MAX_CODONS  6   /* maximum number of codons for one amino acid */
char *AminoAcidCodons[26][MAX_CODONS+1] = {
    /* A */ { "GCT", "GCC", "GCA", "GCT", 0 },
    /* B */ { 0 },
    /* C */ { "TGT", "TGC", 0 },
          :
    /* Y */ { "TAT", "TAC", 0 },
    /* Z */ { 0 },
};
```

Now you can translate an upper-case letter to the set of codons by using a loop:

```
for (i = 0; AminoAcidCodons[aminoAcid1 - 'A'][i]; i++) {
    /* AminoAcidCodons[aminoAcid1-'A'][i] is one of the codons that AminoAcid1 can be encoded as */
     :
```

To get all possible combinations for 5 amino acids, you'll need 5 nested loops.  To deal with lower-case letters, you'll need to translate them to upper-case letters.  You'll also need to deal with invalid codes (non-letters and letters with no corresponding codons).  The functions `isalpha` and `toupper` can help here.